# Creating a thread in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Fiddler to create a new thread to my conversation and I'm following the documentation [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/conversation_post_threads) and I'm getting this error:

```
message="Posts" property missing in create conversation request body.
```

What's really weird is that I'm using the exact request model from the documentation.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/conversations/<id>/threads
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 419

{
  "toRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "name-value",
        "address": "address-value"
      }
    }
  ],
  "topic": "topic-value",
  "hasAttachments": true,
  "lastDeliveredDateTime": "datetime-value",
  "uniqueSenders": [
    "uniqueSenders-value"
  ],
  "ccRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "name-value",
        "address": "address-value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand that clearly the Posts property is missing, but where should this property placed?

Like this,

```
  "topic": "topic-value",
  "Posts": "This is a post"     <<<
  "hasAttachments": true,
```

didn't worked and threw the following error message:

```
"message": "Property Posts in payload has a value that does not match schema."
```

I'd really appreciate your input with this issue.

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
Added the following to the sample model and I was able to create a new thread:

  `"posts": [{}]`

Comment: please post that edit as a solution and accept it.

Comment: @noc2spamツ, two days to accept my own answer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: yupp that should be the normal time for own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I used the same model, but added a posts property and I managed to create a new thread:

```
{
  "toRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "name-value",
        "address": "address-value"
      }
    }
  ],
  "topic": "topic-value",
  "hasAttachments": true,
  "lastDeliveredDateTime": "datetime-value",
  "uniqueSenders": [
    "uniqueSenders-value"
  ],
  "posts": [{}],   <<<< HERE, empty post
  "ccRecipients": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "name-value",
        "address": "address-value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I assume the composition of posts is:

    `"posts": [{
      "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "this is body content"
      },`

Hope it can help someone else in the future.